# Get label value from constant array on drop

Tags: javascript, html

I get the image name of dropped item without .jpg extension in ondrop() in **var x**.

In **var y** i **want** to get the corresponding of x value from item[].

Please drag and drop .box002 to box there are three .box classes with value

Im planning to for a condition check so var y in necessary

how to get it?

how to get var y value?

```js
var tempimages = [];


function rvalue() {
  const items = [  
      { label: '1:40', url: '1.png'  },
      { label: '2:20', url: '2.png'  },
      { label: '3:50', url: '3.png'  },
      { label: '4:45', url: '4.png'  },
      { label: '5:35', url: '5.png'  },
      { label: '6:10', url: '6.png'  },
      { label: '7:15', url: '7.png'  },
      { label: '8:10', url: '8.png'  },
      { label: '9:30', url: '9.png'  }
    ]
   
ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  



for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) 
  {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length),
      
      item = items[randomIndex];
      ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
      tempimages.push(item);
 
  }
 
  
}
 

function displayAllImages() {
  if (tempimages.length === 0) 
  {
    return;
  }
 item = tempimages.shift(),  
    image = document.getElementById('slide');
  image.src = item.url;
};

$(function() {
  
  rvalue();
  displayAllImages(); 
}); 

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  

 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
 var el = document.getElementById(data);
 alert(data);
 alert(el);
 var x=document.getElementById("slide").src.split("/").pop().split(".")[0];
 alert(x);
 var y

  
 //if(x==y)
  {
  el.parentNode.removeChild; 

  
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; 

  var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
  
  displayAllImages();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
    
            <div id="container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>

</div>

    
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">

     <img src=""  draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways, but I prefer to use `data-*` in this case.
If so, you can put on any parameter to your elements.

First, put on `randomIndex` to your elements when you set `ptags[index].textContent = ~`.

```
ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
```

Next, do the same thing in your `slide` element.

```
// in for loop...
tempimages.push({data:item, index: randomIndex});
// in displayAllImages method
image.src = item.data.url;
image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;
```

Then you can pick those `data-*` in the drop method.

```
var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;
```

[For Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxZeEb)